# trying to connect to an azure SQL database with python / pyodbc and a raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

with following code I try to connect to an azure database :

```
server = 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net'
database = 'DBFREE'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

but getting following error :

pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I used following commands to install pyodbc :

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyodbc
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
pip3 install pyodbc
```

thanx in advance

Comment: Please ref the code here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python?tabs=windows#create-code-to-query-your-database

Comment: I spent a good week trying all the same links and articles mentioned here trying to get my Rasberry PIs to connect to an Azure database.    They don't work.   I think it has something to do with the ARM architecture.  So even though Rasberry PI OS is based on Debian and Microsoft supplies the drivers, they don't work.  I ended up using https://www.freetds.org/.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment I recently walked this path and could never get the drivers from Microsoft to work on my Rasberry PIs.  I speculate it has something to do with the ARM architecture. So even though Rasberry PI OS is based on Debian and Microsoft supplies the drivers, I could never get them to work.

I ended up using [FreeTDS](https://www.freetds.org/)

First, install using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin unixodbc-dev tdsodbc
sudo pip install pyodbc sqlalchemy
```

When that is done, open the following file in a text editor:

> /etc/odbcinst.ini

Add the following:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

Then in the python connection string use `FreeTDS` as the driver and add `;TDS_Version=8.0` to the end of the connection string:

```
server = 'servername.database.windows.net'
database = 'database'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
driver = 'FreeTDS'

pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password + ';TDS_Version=8.0')
```

Comment: hello, I seemed to get further, thanx. But now I get following error : 

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

What would cause this error?

Comment: @StevenNoppe I remember now that you have to add ";TDS_Version=8.0" to the end of the connection string.  Try that, I'll go double check mine and update the answer here.

Comment: I think I found the problem : I forget to add to which port I needed to connect!

Answer (score 0):

Please ref the `pyodbc` here: [Quickstart: Use Python to query a database in Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python?tabs=ubuntu#create-code-to-query-your-database)

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

You didn't set the ODBC driver version and the server don't have prefix `tcp:` .

Comment: still doesn't work :( : 
Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: @StevenNoppe Did you install it? please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development#linux

Comment: yes, but I get an error : "Unable to locate package msodbcsql17" on this line : sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17

Comment: @StevenNoppe, can you please test also test ODBC 17 and 13? Download here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If you installed the v17 msodbcsql package that was briefly available, you should remove it before installing the msodbcsql17 package. This will avoid conflicts. The msodbcsql17 package can be installed side by side with the msodbcsql v13 package.

Comment: hello Leon Yue, I already tried your link for installing ODBC 17 (I used Debian 9) but still get the same error. I also tried the v13 :(